# Static variables : How to reclaim memory?

Tags: java, static-members, heap-memory

I created a service that keeps running at the background - it should never go offline.

With each smaller module that I plug-in to the service I'm a little worried about the static variables that I need to use. Since the parent service is up and running always (let's say it never goes down - perfect scenario), won't the static members take up a lot of heap memory with time? Will it eventually cause my service to crash?

From what I know, the static variables persist till program termination - which in this case is never!!

Is there a workaround for this? Can I somehow call my independent modules and not think of the memory used by the static variables - is there any way that they run independently and not eventually end up killing my JVM or service?

PS - I don't think I can do away with the static members, I need to know if there's some efficient way of using static members and not wasting a lot of memory.

Comment: "I don't think I can do away with the static members" - that's what you should be doing though. Your "plugins" shouldn't have any static data.

Comment: @Mat - i would have to do that eventually. I just wanted to know if there's a way this situation can be handled and you still get to use the static variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that *static data members* is the issue here. This is only an OOP design aspect to think about, but it's not related to your memory concerns.

You should first estimate the size of memory your program needs, and then decide whether you really want to keep all this data in main memory during the lifetime of your application. The possible outcomes of this analysis can be:

1. The data must be kept, and it will fit in memory - Configure your -Xmx flag accordingly and test your assumptions.
2. The data must be kept, and there isn't enough space - Consider using persistency (e.g. DB)
3. The data doesn't really have to be kept - Consider using a bounded cache, where old/irrelevant data items are evicted.

Comment: Thanks Eyal! I thought there might be a workaround. I'll design the thing again and avoid the static variables wherever possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you need static variables, then there should be a reason for it. If the content of the static variables is really some property of a class, then it should go into an appropriate class. As the programmer you have to think about your design. static variables are always there by definition. That's the point of having a static in the first place.
If you need to allocate memory, you can of course make only a pointer static and then you can delete this global memory. However, if you really need to this, then it sounds to me like a wrong design.
Static variables should definitely not be the root cause for memory problems.
If you load plugins, then the plugins are responsible for their own memory management and you don't really have control over it anyway.